# Day pilot scheduler control cell rendering issue javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, daypilot-scheduler

I am using day pilot scheduler control . problem is it only rendering cell of the visible area.

**Visible Area :**
[image]

**Scroll**

[image]

I want it to be render all cells at once.